# Identity Server 3 is not persisting authentication cookie

Tags: asp.net-core, identityserver4, openid-connect, identityserver3

I am using IdenttyServer3. I have 3 client applications. 2 applications are developed in .NET Core and 1 is in full .NET.

On login screen if user checked `remember me` option, then user does not have to re-login when switch between applications. If `remember me` option is not selected then user has to login for each application. ( this is working as expected)
So basically, When user check `Remember Me` option it sets persistent cookie. (My Guess)

Now, instead of giving user `Remember Me` option i always wants cookie to persist so user does not have to re-login while switching between the applications. So as per the documentation i set `IsPersistent` to true and `AllowRemmberMe` to `false`

```
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {           
        DataProtectionProvider = app.GetDataProtectionProvider();

        app.Map("/identity", idsrvApp =>
        {
            var identityServerOptions = new IdentityServerOptions
            {
                SiteName = "my Login",
                SigningCertificate = LoadCertificateFromWindwosStore(ApplicationConfig.SigningCertificateSubjectName),
                RequireSsl = true,
                Factory = new IdentityServerServiceFactory()
                    .Configure(),
                AuthenticationOptions = new AuthenticationOptions()
                {
                    CookieOptions = new IdentityServer3.Core.Configuration.CookieOptions()
                    {
                        //forced user to log back in after the Client (ie MVC App) cookie expires
                        ExpireTimeSpan = System.TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5),
                        SlidingExpiration = false,

                        //Indicates whether the authentication cookie is marked as persistent. Defaults to false.
                        IsPersistent = true,
                        
                        AllowRememberMe = false                            
                    },
                    EnableAutoCallbackForFederatedSignout = true,
                    EnableSignOutPrompt = false
                },
                EventsOptions = new EventsOptions().Configure(),
                EnableWelcomePage = ApplicationConfig.EnableWelcomePage
            };

            idsrvApp.UseIdentityServer(identityServerOptions);                
        });            
    }
```

[image]

However, this does not create persistent cookie. The `Remember Me` option is gone from login screen but user always have to login when switching between the applications.

**UPDATE 1**
As i mentioned earlier when `remember me` check box is checked, then it creates persistent cookie and user doesn't need to re-login. So on login page, i harcoded checkbox to true and hide the check box. That worked. But i dont think that is correct soultion.  I would like to know what is the correct solution and why setting `IsPersistent` to true in code not working

To get it working i set `ng-show` to `false` and `ng-checked` to `true`

```
<!--<div class="col-md-6" ng-show="model.allowRememberMe">-->

     <div class="col-md-6" ng-show="false">
          <input type="checkbox" id="rememberMe" name="rememberMe" 
                 ng-model="model.rememberMe" value="true" ng-checked="true">
          <span>Remember Me</span>
     </div>
```

Comment: @NadeemTaj why?

Comment: may be i didnt understand your question. What my client application name has to do with the my question? in-fact what is client application name? You meant VS solution name or domain name?

Comment: please count those comments irrelevant. Forget about that.

Answer (score 0):

It has to do with the way cookies work, while I'm not sure the functionality actually exists in IdentityServer3 to configure the cookies, you can't have a single authentication server giving out auth to two different domains if it just uses cookies. You would need a more indepth authentication provider to handle something like that for you.